# php is treated as comment

Tags: php, comments

I have downloaded a web site with HTTrack to test my google map inside an existing page file. I changed the .html file to .php . I have to include a file

```
<?php include 'map.php'; ?>
```

and place this code inside a div

```
    <div id = "mapContainer" >
        <div id = "map-canvas"></div>
        <div id = "directionSlider" ></div> 
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        initialize(document.getElementById("map-canvas"));
    </script>
```

The problem is:

```
<?php include 'map.php'; ?>
```

is auto generated as

```
<!--?php include 'map.php'; ?-->
```

when i see the page source code.

It is commented. The map works great in other files, any suggestions?

Comment: This is not really a programming question, just an issue with HTTRack.  ALthough you can fix it with programming, simply write a script to remove all comments from php files ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The php code needs to be executed on the server. This will then replace php code with whatever the output of 'map.php' is, before sending it to the browser. The problem you've got is that you are giving the browser code that has not had the php evaluated. Therefore, the php code is still in the html. The browser doesn't know what php is and so does the safest thing which is to comment it out.

EDIT: If you are running this code locally then you can install a server on your own computer. Google LAMP, WAMP or XAMPP for linux, windows and mac respectively.

Comment: The problem was that i did not run the .php file from xampp localhost :S Lets forget about this question :p ty a lot